# ElasticSearch - Health Query

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

When I run the [following query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_cluster_health.html) on my ElasticSearch instance:

> GET /_cat/nodes?v

I get this response:

> heap.percent 26
>
> ram.percent 73
>
> cpu 0
>
> load_1m 0.01
>
> load_5m 0.04
>
> load_15m 0.00
>
> diskAvail 160GB

I am concerned about the ram.percent. Here is [explanation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-nodes.html) of what those values mean, but 73% looks like a lot. Do I need to be worried, and if yes what are the steps to take to prevent something bad from happening?

I have around 70 indexes. Smallest one is around 50kb (10 or more documents). The largest one is 800MB (around 700k documents). It is [ELK](https://www.elastic.co/webinars/introduction-elk-stack) stack, with default settings.

My AWS EC2 instance has i7CPU (equivalent), 64GB ram and SSD 500GB.

INFO:
I do not have any [fielddata](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_limiting_memory_usage.html). And [queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_limiting_memory_usage.html) that check for fielddata are 0 bytes.